# Something is generating spam pages on my site

Tags: plugins, spam

The site is Videos-de-musica.com it is a simple wordpress blog with music videos. Somehow the subdomain stats.videos-de-musica.com filled up with spam, I remember setting the domain for pwiki stats, but then uninstalled it and I don't remember what happened to it.

This is an example spam page stats.videos-de-musica.com/aal-0exe.htm

When you search PRINTABLE SUPERMAN EMBLEM BATMAN on Google that is the first result, and when you access it you are redirected to a "Google has found malicious software may be installed onto your computer if you proceed" scam site.

I have tried disabling all the plugins with no change.

Does anybody know what happened and how to remove this?

I am downloading all the site directory to search for any clues.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably downloaded a theme or plugin that added a *"backdoor."*  [Otto](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/users/2232/otto) has a good post on the subject:

- [**How to find a backdoor in a hacked WordPress**](http://ottopress.com/2009/hacked-wordpress-backdoors/)

Comment: Wow, that was really useful, I searched for base64 and from there found a directory with TXT files with the spam content. I will now try to find the source and delete from there.

BTW, it was in the wpau-backup folder, for automated backups. I don't know if that was the script responsable for the backdoor or I was just the folder used.

Thanks!

Comment: @JavierRey - Glad I was able to help!